# withSender suffix when migrating a project to swift 3

Tags: swift

I have an old Xcode project written in Swift 2.
I have opened this project with Xcode last version. I did not migrate to Swift 3. I have instead change an option in build settings (Swift legacy to YES).

Now I want to migrate to Swift 3. I have put this swift option to NO and I have checked each line of code to change to Swift 3 syntax.

I have a problem in storyboard (Interface Builder). All my `@IBAction` show a "withSender" suffix. I had to delete and re-create all `@IBAction` bindings.

What is this "withSender" suffix? Is it a bug?

It is a Cocoa project.
It is very strange because Interface Builder shows me a function name with "withSender" suffix but as you can see on screen shot, real Swift code do not have this suffix...

[image]

```
@IBAction func on_btn_quitter(sender: NSButton) {
    NSApp.terminate(nil)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Code should be posted as formatted text, not as a picture.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a change in Swift 3.  The first parameter name is now required when calling a function.

For example, if you have a function `foo(bar: Int)`, then this is called with `foo(7)` in Swift 2, but with `foo(bar: 7)` in Swift 3.

This affects the way the function name is translated into an *Objective C Selector*.  If the first parameter name is required, it becomes a part of the selector.  The first parameter name is added by appending `WithParametername`.  Since Swift 3 defaults to requiring the first parameter name, it is now necessary to add `_` before the first parameter name to suppress that behavior to get the same *Selector* name as Swift 2.

Here is a table to show the relationship of the *Objective C* selector and the Swift `func` syntax:

```
ObjC Selector         Swift 3                 Swift 2
-------------  --------------------   ----------------------
fooWithBar:    func foo(bar: Int)     func foo(bar bar: Int)
foo:           func foo(_ bar: Int)   func foo(bar: Int)
```

Usually Xcode make this translation for you when converting, but I suspect that since you first went to Swift 2.3 and then to Swift 3 you ended up with untranslated function signatures.

To fix this manually, add `_` before your first parameter name:

```
@IBAction func on_btn_quitter(_ sender: NSButton)
```

Comment: @Bob5421, did this answer your question?